# GREP using a regex expression group

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to parse some apache access.log and get the user agent.
a line looks like

```
54.183.192.175 - - [27/Nov/2015:16:52:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 329 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
```

I went to  reg101 site and ended up with the expression    `.*".*".*".*"(.*)"`    which in the site perfectly matches the user agent.
then I tried to use that regex in a grep command and it simply does not return anything.

I tried with single quotes and scapeing the double quotes withtout success. someone could point it to me how should I do it?

```
grep -o '.*".*".*".*"(.*)"' access.log   -- no results at all

grep -o .*\".*\".*\".*\"(.*)\" access.log   -- error `bash: syntax
```

> error near unexpected token `('`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract string in last pair of `""`, `awk` would be simplest solution:

```sh
awk -F '"' '{print $(NF-1)}' httpd.log
```

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
```

**How it works:**

- By using `-F '"'` we use `"` as field separator
- `$(NF-1)` gets `last - 1` field

Answer (score 1):

You defined literal parentheses with `(` and `)` in your POSIX BRE pattern.

You may extract the substring you need with either of

```
grep -oP '.*"\K[^"]+' file
sed -n 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p' file
# => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
```

In `grep -oP '.*"\K[^"]+' file`, a PCRE regex engine is used due to `-P` option. The pattern matches up to the last `"`, omits the match (as `\K` is a PCRE operator that discards all text matched so far) and then one one or more chars other than `"` land in the match value. As the `-o` option is used, the match is the return value.

In `sed -n 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p'`, the regex matches all up to the last occurrence of `"`, any zero or more chars (captured into Group 1), `"` and then the rest of the string, and the match is replaced with the contents of Group 1. This is what is returned since `-n` suppresses default line output and `p` prints the result of the substitution.

Comment: sed command worked perfectly. Sadly I am not capable to understand the logic behind :(

for the grep , the suggested command does not work. Only shows one line and there are more than 200.

what is wrong about defining literal parentheses with ()? cannot grep use that?

Comment: @YaKs If `grep` does not work for you, you are not using GNU grep. Please consider installing `pcregrep` and use it with `-o` option. `(` and `)` in a POSIX  BRE pattern are literal parentheses, not group delimiters. Either escape them or use `-E` option.

Comment: I just checked once again the regex used in your grep command and it works fine if there is a single apache log line in the file. with more than one, it only extracts the last one. i guess the new line is not considered in your regex.

Comment: @YaKs Not sure what you mean by "not considered". See [demo](https://ideone.com/p3VCcw) with several log lines. Here is a [sed demo](https://ideone.com/34Q2KS).